# Sum of all primes under 2 million with threads giving incorrect answer

Tags: c++, multithreading, sum

So my code which gets all primes correctly is this and gives the result 142,913,828,922.

loop for summing primes

```
for (int i = 2; i < 2000001; i++){
        if (isPrime(i)){
            sum += i;
        }
    }
```

But I when I was trying to create it initially, I decided I would try to distribute the tasks into threads so it would run faster and I originally came up with this:

in the main:

```
thread first(threadF, 2, 1000001, std::ref(sum));
thread second(threadF, 1000000, 1750001, std::ref(sum));
thread third(threadF, 1750000, 1900001, std::ref(sum));
thread fourth(threadF, 1900000, 2000001, std::ref(sum));
first.join();
second.join();
third.join();
fourth.join();
```

with threadF being

```
void threadF(int lowerBound, int upperBound, unsigned long long int &sum){
for (lowerBound; lowerBound < upperBound; lowerBound++){
    if (isPrime(lowerBound)){
        sum += lowerBound;
        cout << "prime" << lowerBound << endl;
    }
}}
```

I just kinda split them thinking the higher numbers would take longer but didn't do any math to determine how I should split them. My problem is that when I use threads, I don't get a consistent answer. Every time, I've gotten close to the other method's solution, but never exact and the answers aren't always the same. usually they're off by a few million or so. I was just doing this to learn a bit about threads and while solving a eulers project problem not for any practical reason.

Comment: data race,many thread write sum ,sum should be atomic.

Comment: you could also use 4 separate variables sum0, sum1, sum2, sum3 and sum them all together after all the threads finish, if there is a performance penalty for using atomics

Comment: Or each thread has it own sum,when all thread run over. sum them together.

Comment: Thanks guys you guys. I wasn't aware of the term atomic before but am currently reading the c++ documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You program has data race with sum.
And you have three options, the first use of atomic types of variables, and the second, using thread-local variables.Or use different var name as sum0,1..
when all thread run over,sum them together.

If you could use C++11,[atomic](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic) or [thread_local](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/storage_duration) maybe meet your need.